# Reading atom feeds title and posted datetime

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I guess this isn't new at all but I couldn't find a trustworthy link to help me read atom feeds correctly. I would like only to get the feed's title, posted date and time. For example, in the following link
http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/atom.aspx
I would like display

```
Title 1: The Case of My Mom’s Broken Microsoft Security Essentials Installation   
Date time : 1-5-2005 12:00    
Title 2:.....
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/atom.aspx");
XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");

var info = xdoc.Root
            .Descendants(ns+"entry")
            .Select(n =>
                new
                {
                    Title = n.Element(ns+"title").Value,
                    Time = DateTime.Parse(n.Element(ns+"published").Value),
                }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 8):

The .Net framework exposes a set of Classes and API's, specifically for working with Syndicated XML Feeds, including RSS 2.0 and Atom 1.0, they can be found in the [System.ServiceModel.Syndication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.aspx) namespace.

The basic classes are:
[System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationFeed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.items.aspx) represents an Atom or RSS formatted XML Feed. 
[System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationitem.aspx) represents the Items within the Feed, "entry" or "Item" elements, these are exposed as a property of the SyndicationFeed [IEnumerable Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.items.aspx).

Personally I prefer to use the classes and API's exposed in the System.ServiceModel.Syndication namespace rather than Linq to XML as you are working directly with strongly types objects not ambiguous XElements.

```
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(this.Url);
            request.Timeout = Timeout;

            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);

                if (feed != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in feed.Items)
                    {
                         // Work with the Title and PubDate properties of the FeedItem
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: @ScottE You can also call WebResponse.GetResponse() in a separate thread with a timeout which will catch any timeout on the response. The WebRequest.Timeout only applies to the initrial server response, if you then loose the connection it will hang.

Answer (score 1):

try this Linq to xml query,

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/atom.aspx");
XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
var xmlFeed = from post in xml.Descendants(ns + "entry")
              select new
              {
                   Title = post.Element(ns + "title").Value,
                   Time = DateTime.Parse(post.Element(ns + "published").Value)
              };
```